# Can Ubuntu and Windows be installed in dual boot configuration when one OS is UEFI and the other is BIOS/legacy?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, uefi, windows, bios

I have been running 18.04 on an M.2 for a couple years. I now would like to install Windows 10 on a seperate NVME. While preparing, I came across a distinction of "BIOS" boot vs. "UEFI" boot. It is suggested that both OS should use the same bootloader.

However, I found my 18.04 is using a Bios bootloader (I am not sure how this happened). I am unsure if/how this should impact my install of Windows 10.  I was curious what this means for installing Windows on the seperate NVME. I can imagine a few scenarios:

1. Proceed installing Windows 10 (i.e. everything is fine)
2. Reinstall 18.04 (or 20.04) as UEFI (new Ubuntu without BIOS bootloader).
3. Convert 18.04 BIOS --> 18.04 UEFI boot loader.
4. Install Windows 10 as Bios/Legacy

What is the best way to go about getting Windows 10 installed in this case?

Comment: How it boot - the installer - is how it installs. So that's why you have what you have. Now you need to keep in mind that Windows strictly requires GPT partitioning type for UEFI mode and MBR for Legacy/CSM/"BIOS". Adjust your expectations and workflow from now on accordingly.

Comment: If I understand your comment, it sounds I need either (1) MBR partitioning on M.2 for the Windows or (2) Reinstall Ubuntu on old M.2 as UEFI and GPT parition the Windows M.2

Comment: UEFI/GPT is preferable but if you don't want to change what you currently have then make sure you're booting the Windows installer in the intended mode.

Comment: Also of note: If you end up installing Windows in Legacy mode you  won't be able to upgrade it to Windows 11 that no longer support Legacy.

Comment: MBR partitioned drives are limited to 4 partitions. A typical Windows installation uses 4 partitions. If it were me, I would format (erase) the disk as GPT and reinstall both operating systems cleanly. Install Windows first, then Ubuntu. Because Ubuntu 18.04's community support ends in 7 months, I would install a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: If your machine allows you to set the booting preference (UEFI before legacy  etc.) then since you are on different disks, you can install in different modes. Just realize your grub menu will not boot Windows in the "other" mode, you need to boot the Windows device, so invoke the EFI menu (some function key at bootup).

Comment: "Reinstall 18.04 (or 20.04) as UEFI (new Ubuntu without BIOS bootloader)." and why not "Reinstall 22.04 as UEFI (new Ubuntu without BIOS bootloader)."? Seems to me the better option out of all of those. "What is the best way to go about getting Windows 10 installed in this case?" is asking for options and off topic: Ubuntu is not part of this question.

Comment: @Nmath: MBR partition drives can have lots of partitions, as long as one of them is extended and contains all but three of the other partitions. Ubuntu only needs to be installed UEFI if you want GRUB to also boot Windows.

Comment: Let's not be pedantic or complicate the issue unnecessarily. MBR is hard limited to 4 primary partitions. Both Ubuntu and Windows must be installed to primary partitions. The additional partitions that Windows needs also must be primary partitions. For the purpose of this discussion, we do not need to get into the topic of extended partitions.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. I now have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed on two seperate M.2s. Both have UEFI boots. However, when I boot the PC, it automatically boots ubuntu. Is this the expected behavior?  I was anticipating getting to the grub menu where I could pick which OS to boot.

Comment: @Jacob Anderson: Set Ubuntu to boot first in BIOS. once Ubuntu is working run `sudo update-grub`in Terminal and it will add Windows to the GRUB boot menu, ( 20.04 and earlier). OS Prober is disabled in 22.04.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron. Thank you so much. I really appreciate everyone's input and the community atmosphere. I now have my first dual boot - grub menu included. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Nmath: You say "Both Ubuntu and Windows must be installed to primary partitions" Are you sure? Ubuntu works okay for me installed on the logical drives of an extended partition.